# How to create a custom layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Im trying to build a layout like the image below, but i cant figure that out.
I have tried building that with relative layot but the viewFlipper overlays with videoView on center.
Here is my main layout.

[image: Cant figure out building a layout like the]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_divi"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63.85dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/foto_lart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="206dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ticker"
       android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myvideoview"
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

       <ViewFlipper
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
           android:animateFirstView="true"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:foregroundGravity="fill" />
   </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_divi"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scrollIndicators="left"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myvideoview" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

         <TextView   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            />
         <TextView   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            />  
          <TextView   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            />   
         </TableRow>   


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why is the ViewFlipper inside a LinearLayout? And the TableLayout is missing a closing **>**

Comment: I was trying something else and copied te latest changed code. What im trying to achieve is to maintain that type of layout fixed and not to overlap.

Comment: I would set up first the upper ad lower Views. Tahn the one on the right than the one on the bottom (over the already bottomed one) and at last the bigger one. Without even using a TableLayout.

Comment: ViewFlipper is the main problem it overlays with the videoView part.

Comment: Try to review the **relativity** between your Views. Avoiding circular  references.

Comment: Can u help me on that, i have tried but with no results.

Comment: Not in the immediate, since I'm going to sleep. Possibly in 12 hours.

Comment: Is there any other technique on building that other than relative layout

Comment: Many. GridLayout, TableLayout, ... I find myself comfortable with the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Okay thanks, waiting on your solution. Thanks

Comment: See you later. Or maybe someone "more awake" than me will answer sooner.

Comment: Hope someone will..many thanks

Comment: Well, it's not a hard question to answer, so... the possibilities that someone will do that are high.

Comment: Can you please help or give me some ideas how to figure that out

Comment: I thought that @dhina already gave in a solution. Unfortunately my right arm is enclosed in a "cage" and I can't be much productive now.

Comment: Maybe in a few days I'll be able to master this "armoured" arm (I broke the right one!)

Comment: Meanwhile, investigate the RelativeLayout in depth. And possibly use some good old low-tech paper and pencil to design your layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106112/discussion-between-aldo-and-bob-malooga).

Answer (score 0):

Using LinearLayout this way.. make sure to change the image/text/color etc..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ticker"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:scrollIndicators="left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="marquee"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateFirstView="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try and will notify about the results.

Comment: it is not working the way im trying to achieve. the videoview changes depending on videos resolution and either the viewflipper is small.
What im trying to achieve is to maintain a fixed layout.

Comment: try wrapping the video view inside a relative layout

Comment: still not working, let me explain better what im trying. So i want the layout on the image to be absolute, no overlapping or dynamic changes.
It will be used on digital signage on tv. (not android tv)